# Spring Kafka. Not started EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am coding Kafka Broker and Consumer to catch messages from the application. When trying to get messages from Consumer, an error occurs

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:531)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:540)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:444)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1267)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(KafkaTestUtils.java:303)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(KafkaTestUtils.java:280)
```

On the application side (Producer), there is also a connection error

```
2020-03-25 12:29:33.689  WARN 25786 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=tx0] Connection to node -1 (<here broker hostname>:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

My project has the following dependencies:

```
compile "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.4.4.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.4.4.RELEASE"
```

Code of My Kafka Broker

```
public class KafkaServer {

    private static final String BROKERPORT = "9092";
    private static final String BROKERHOST = "localhost";
    public static final String TOPIC1 = "fss-fsstransdata";
    public static final String TOPIC2 = "fss-fsstransscores";
    public static final String TOPIC3 = "fss-fsstranstimings";
    public static final String TOPIC4 = "fss-fssdevicedata";
    @Getter
    private Consumer<String, String> consumer;

    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    public void run() {

        String[] topics = {TOPIC1, TOPIC2, TOPIC3, TOPIC4};

        this.embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(
                1,
                false,
                1,
                topics
        ).kafkaPorts(BROKERPORT);

        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("consumer", "false", this.embeddedKafkaBroker));
        this.consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer()).createConsumer();

        this.consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topics));
    } 
}
```

Please help to deal with the situation. I am not good at kafka architecture and how it can be implemented on Spring.

Comment: Kafka consumer is not the same as Kafka broker by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` is designed to be used from a Spring application context or  by a JUnit4 `@Rule` or `@ClassRule` or by a JUnit5 `Condition`.

To use it outside those environments, you must call `afterPropertiesSet()` to initialize it and `destroy()` to shut it down.

Comment: Hello, Gary! Thank u for answer. I used afterPropertiesSet() after EmbeddedKafkaBroker creating, problem "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" disappeared. My stub still does not receive messages from the application, and there are no errors, but that's another story )

Comment: If you are using it in a test case, the most common reason for not receiving a message is because it's sent before the consumer is assigned the partitions. Set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest` - it's `latest` by default so you won't get any records that are already in the topic when you get assigned.

Comment: No, my problem is that the producer cannot connect to the kafka broker, I configured something incorrectly. I decided that I would try to deploy the kafka server on one of the linux test stand and send messages to it )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring then you need to annotate your bean with **@EmbeddedKafka** and then use **@Autowire** on EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Example embeded kafka annotation configuration:

```
@EmbeddedKafka(
    partitions = 1, 
    controlledShutdown = false,
    brokerProperties = {// place your proerties here
})
```

What I would do is to create a spring bean **KafkaServerConfig** and place all my logic for configuration and bean construction inside.

PS: it should be noted that EmbeddedKafkaBroker is intended for unit tests.

Comment: Hello, Alexander, thank u for answer!  
  
Is it possible to do all this without using annotations and DI ? I would like to do without creating a spring context that is create all needed objects manually in code.  
  
p.s. I need a Kafka stub to verify the correctness of sent messages from the application that sends messages to kafka, nothing else